# Adding virtual specifier in a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual

Consider following code:

```
struct virtualfoo 
{
    virtualfoo{};
    virtual ~virtualfoo{};

    virtual double doStuff() = 0
};


struct realbar :  virtualfoo   
{
     realbar{};
     virtual ~realbar{};

     virtual double doStuff();
};
```

Since I want to implement `doStuff()` for `realbar`, virtual isn't mandatory. But if I get this right, it won't hurt to have the virtual specifier next to `realbar::doStuff()`, does it?
What side effects could I get with using/not using virtual?

Comment: You're missing the return type of `doStuff()` -- but there are no side effects to having/not having the `virtual` keyword in the derived classes.  Typically, I feel it gives clarity to include it.  Also, if you use the `override` keyword in your derived classes, you'll get a compiler error if you change the base class and not the derived classes, can be very helpful:  `virtual void doStuff() override` (in the `realbar` class definition)

Comment: edit: changed the return type ;)

ty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The virtual keyword is not necessary in the derived class. However it makes code clearer. Also in *C++11* `override` keyword is introduced which allows the source code to clearly specify that a member function is *intended* to override a base class method.

With keyword `override` the compiler will check the base class(es) to see if there is a virtual function with this exact signature. And if there is not, the compiler will throws an error.

Comment: It doesn't make things clearer as much as override. It can just as easily add a new virtual function by mistake if mistyping. Better just use override. It's clear and correct by virtue of simply compiling successfully. But +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @StoryTeller Agreed. But few people are stuck with pre C++11 compiler, where IMHO specifying `virtual` keyword in sources helps in code review.

Comment: I'm not sold. I actually once had a colleague of mine pulling at his hairs because he couldn't understand why his override was being called (`OnEvent` instead of `onEvent`). I still remember his cries of "But I marked it virtual!". Code review spotted it, thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you explicitly declare `realbar::doStuff` as virtual, since it is implicitly `virtual` due to `virtualfoo:doStuff` being virtual. So no side effects; `realbar::doStuff` will be virtual anyway. Confer, for example, this [online C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> 10.3 Virtual functions
>
> (2) If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in
>   a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5),
>   cv-qualification, and ref- qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf
>   is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so
>   declared) and it overrides Base::vf. ...